# Python 3.5.2 Socket Keep-Alive

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, keep-alive

I am trying to set a keep alive flag for my socket. I'm using Python 3.5.2. Here's the code:

```
ConnectionSocket, address = ServerSocket.accept()

ConnectionSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE,1)
ConnectionSocket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 1)
ConnectionSocket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPINTVL, 3)
ConnectionSocket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPCNT, 5)
```

But I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/QuizServer/QuizServer/MultiplexingServer.py", line 135, in <module>
    ConnectionSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE,1)
AttributeError: type object 'socket' has no attribute 'SOL_SOCKET'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

How do you import your socket library and how do you define your server socket? This is missing from your code snippet.

```
import socket

ServerSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ServerSocket.bind((socket.gethostname(), 4224))
ServerSocket.listen(0)
ConnectionSocket, address = ServerSocket.accept()


ConnectionSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE,1)
ConnectionSocket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 1)
ConnectionSocket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPINTVL, 3)
ConnectionSocket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPCNT, 5)
```

This code works with Python3.5 and does not produce any errors.

Hannu